# Transferir registros de una tabla a otra agregando subtotal

Tags: mysql

Como puedo transferir esta Tabla_origen que tiene registros D (Debe):

```
ID  MOV IMPORTE CLASE
1   1   100.00  D
2   1   200.00  D
3   1   50.00   D
4   2   450.00  D
5   2   80.00   D
6   3   30.00   D
7   3   50.00   D
8   3   70.00   D
```

Y que en la nueva Tabla_Destino por cada Mov inserte un total, de esta manera:

```
ID  MOV IMPORTE CLASE
1   1   100.00  D
2   1   200.00  D
3   1   50.00   D
4   1   350.00  H
5   2   450.00  D
6   2   80.00   D
7   2   530.00  H
8   3   30.00   D
9   3   50.00   D
10  3   70.00   D
11  3   150.00  H
```

Estoy preparando una tabla MySQL y como lo veo tal vez tenga que hacer varios pasos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pienso que lo podrías hacer en dos pasos...

Primero, copiar los datos de la tabla origen a la tabla destino:

```
insert into Tabla_destino (ID, MOV, IMPORTE, CLASE)
select ID, MOV, IMPORTE, CLASE from Tabla_origen;
```

Luego, calcular los subtotales e insertarlos en la tabla destino:

```
insert into Tabla_destino (ID, MOV, IMPORTE, CLASE)
select @row := @row + 1 as ID, MOV, sum(IMPORTE) as IMPORTE, 'H' as CLASE
from Tabla_destino as D, (SELECT @row := (select MAX(ID)+1 from Tabla_origen)) as R
group by MOV;
```

Si la columna `ID` es autonumerada, entonces la consulta queda mucho más simple, no necesitas la variable `@row`.

Comment: Al intentar el insert me muestra el siguiente mensaje: _#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias_

Comment: Fijate ahora, actualicé la respuesta

Comment: Y para generar la tabla como el modelo que puse, debería crear otra tabla y utilizar Order By MOV, CLASE. Cierto?

Comment: Si quieres que los `ID` te queden en el orden que decías, sí. Aunque no se para qué querrías los `ID` de esa forma, el orden lo puedes resolver cuando hagas la consulta sobre la tabla...

Comment: Es el requerimiento que me dieron, por eso el orden debe estar en el ID.

Answer (score 1):

Una de las ventajas de las base de datos es que no tienen que agregarse ordenadamente, con que los muestres de esa forma basta.

puedes simplemente copiar todos los datos `INSERT INTO tabla_Destino 
SELECT * FROM tabla_Origen`

y luego con un procedimiento almacenado mandar a llamar un cursor para cada

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insertar_total()
BEGIN

 DECLARE v_terminado INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE v_mov INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

 DEClARE mov_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT mov FROM tabla_origen;

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_terminado = 1;

 OPEN mov_cursor;

 WHILE terminado = 0 DO

 FETCH mov_cursor INTO v_mov;
 INSERT INTO tabla_destino VALUES (NULL, v_mov, (SELECT SUM(importE) FROM tabla_origen WHERE mov = v_mov), 'H' );


 END WHILE;

 CLOSE email_cursor;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Luego mandas a llamar a tu procedimiento `CALL insertar_total();`

Y las ordenas para que el total aparezca abajo de cada movimiento

```
SELECT * FROM tabla_destino ORDER BY mov ASC, clase ASC;
```

EDITO, quizá una forma más sencilla sería

```
INSERT INTO tabla destino
SELECT NULL, mov, SUM(importe), 'h',  FROM tabla_Origen GROUP BY mov;
```

Y al igual que antes solo te quedaría al momento de llamarla ordenarla

`SELECT * FROM tabla_Destino ORDER BY mov ASC, clase ASC`

Comment: Me parece interesante, pero este cursor sería siempre y cuando sea un proceso recurrente. En mi caso solo estoy preparando / depurando una gran tabla. Y ese cursor funciona en cualquier esquema MySQL?

Comment: Los cursores son de mysql nativos, puedes checar la documentación oficial https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html (ojo, mysql, desconozco si para el sql en general). pero me parece tienes razón, al empezar a escribir la respuesta no se me ocurría otra forma, pero recién se me ocurrió otra más sencilla, pruébala, edité mi respuesta, y  me dices si agarró

Answer (score 1):

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si el valor de la columna `ID` en la tabla `TABLA_DESTINO` no es auto-generado, entonces se puede hacer:

```
INSERT INTO TABLA_DESTINO (ID, MOV, IMPORTE, CLASE)
SELECT
    @id := @id + 1,
    t.MOV,
    t.IMPORTE,
    t.CLASE
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ID,
        MOV,
        IMPORTE,
        CLASE
    FROM
        TABLA_ORIGEN
    UNION ALL
        SELECT
        1,
        MOV,
        SUM(IMPORTE),
        'H'
    FROM
        TABLA_ORIGEN
    GROUP BY
        MOV
    ) AS t,
    (
    SELECT @id := 0 FROM DUAL
    ) AS i
ORDER BY t.MOV, t.CLASE, t.ID
```

Asumiendo que la columna `ID` en la tabla `TABLA_DESTINO` tiene el atributo `AUTO_INCREMENT` puedes utilizar el siguiente comando:

```
INSERT INTO TABLA_DESTINO (MOV, IMPORTE, CLASE)
SELECT
    t.MOV,
    t.IMPORTE,
    t.CLASE
FROM (
    SELECT
        ID,
        MOV,
        IMPORTE,
        CLASE
    FROM
        TABLA_ORIGEN
    UNION ALL
        SELECT
        1,
        MOV,
        SUM(IMPORTE),
        'H'
    FROM
        TABLA_ORIGEN
    GROUP BY
        MOV
) AS t
ORDER BY t.MOV, t.CLASE, t.ID
```

Comment: Interesante, aunque el ID no es autoincrement. Igual probaré modificando  ese campo.